How does one act with lowering operators on a (00) Dynkin label in a weight diagram
I am trying to learn some representation theory and am currently reading through some notes I found online on highest-weight representations (see http://mf23.web.rice.edu/LA_8_v2.3%20Highest%20weight%20representations.pdf if you are interested of the source) on highest-weight representations. In particular, I was interested on how one constructs weight trees, and I think I get the hang of it (sort of at least).
I found two weight trees, one for $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ for the (11) representation. See the image below.

As of my understanding, if we start with any representation denoted by its' highest weight, say (11), we can subtract rows from the Cartan matrix (corresponding to simple roots) to construct the rest of the weights depending on the signs. As (1,1) contains two positive values, we can subtract both with the first or second row in the Cartan matrix. Next up for (-1,2) we can subtract only with the second row, and so forth. Here, I also see that we can subtract the first or second row for the (0,0) weight.
However, further down the notes I also found this for $\mathfrak{so}(7)$.

Here instead, we are only allowed to subtract with the third row of the Cartan matrix it seems like. Why would for example the first or second row not be valid in this case? I suppose I am missing some important detail on when you can subtract simple roots from a given weight.

I suppose the easiest way is just to use the Weyl symmetries, and don't use subtraction on non-dominant weights.

@Trebor I am curious, can the Weyl symmetries explain why it seems that if you act with a lowering operator and end up in a (00) state, that you have to walk with that lowering operator again to produce the rest of the weights? It seems to be a pattern I have noticed in these diagrams.

I don't understand your "we are only allowed to subtract with the third row of the Cartan matrix it seems like". $\overline{\alpha}_{i}$ is the $i$-th row of the Cartan matrix, and represnts the difference of the two vectors in the box connected by the edge.

@A.Kato Yes precisely, they represent the difference of two vectors in the box connected by the edge as you say. So ultimately my question is, how come in the first image one can subtract with both rows, whereas in the latter case only subtraction of one of the rows is valid.

@A.Kato What about the case when all the Dynkin coefficients are precisely 0?

@A.Kato But in these pictures they act on lowering operators even if all Dynkin coefficients are all 0, right? Or have I misunderstood something?

I think Section 21 of "Finite dimensional modules" of Humphreys "Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation Theory" (GTM 9) is helpful.
